# Time series, using quarters but giving me an error message

Tags: r, regression

Error in quarter(., SALE_DATE, with_year = FALSE, fiscal_start = 1) :
unused argument (SALE_DATE)

Comment: Can you explain more about your parameters? what is "RESIDENTIAL_UNITS"?

Comment: to me the question is incredibly unclear. if we don't know the variables, what constitutes the right solution or even more than that, what to regress? I suggest reading something like http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/168-multiple-linear-regression-in-r/ or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moderndive/vignettes/why-moderndive.html

Comment: If you have a specific problem or issue with the code, do edit your question again. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few notes about using regression models. First of all, you need to know the type of variables you have. IF the variable is continuous you can simply use it, but if it's in a binary format (or dummy format) I recommend using `as.factor` for it. In your case, I am guessing that **RESIDENTIAL_UNITS** is a binary variable, so I recommend using `as.factor(RESIDENTIAL_UNITS)`. Also, you don't need to separate variables and create 4 separate models. You can combine them in one model and finally in the summary report, you can find the significance of each parameter, so I recommend writing it in this form:

```
model1 <- lm(formula = SALE_PRICE ~ GROSS_SQUARE_FEET+as.factor(RESIDENTIAL_UNITS)+
YEAR_BUILT+SALE_DATE,data= combine1)
summary(model1)
```